# Why does my custom sort() function cannot be accepted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I tried to upgrade the current custom sort function of JavaScript to create a new order of sorting 
***e.g. (1, 2, 3, 4,..., !@#$%^=+, a, A, b, B, c, C)***

```js
function getSortOrder(prop) {
    return function (a, b) {
        if (isSpecialChar(a[prop], 0) || isSpecialChar(b[prop], 0)) {
            return sortData(a[prop], b[prop]);
        }
        if (isNumeric(a[prop], 0) == "number" || isNumeric(b[prop], 0) == "number") {
            return getSortNumeric(a[prop], b[prop]);
        }
        if (isLetter(a[prop], 0) || isLetter(b[prop], 0)) {
            return getSortLetter(a[prop], b[prop]);
        }
    };
}


function getSortLetter(a, b) {
    if ((a.charAt(0) === getLowerCase(a, 0)) && (b.charAt(0) === getUpperCase(b, 0))) {
        return sortData(a, b);
    }
    return sortData(a, b);
}
function getSortNumeric(a, b) {
    if (typeof a[prop] == "number") {
        return (a[prop] - b[prop]);
    } else {
        return ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : ((a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : 0));
    }
}

function sortData(a, b) {
    if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Function that is used for the ascending order of number
 *
 */
const sortNumberData = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true })

// to check if the data has numeric
function isNumeric(str, index) {
    let x = /^[0-9]$/.test(str.charAt(index));
    console.log(str, x);
    return x;
}

// to determine if the data has neither numeric or letter

function isSpecialChar(str, index) {
    return !isNumeric(str, index) && !isLetter(str, index);
}

// to specify the order of letter e.g. (jane doe, Jane Doe, john doe, John doe)

function isLetter(str, index) {
    return str.charAt(index).length === 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i);
}
function getLowerCase(str, index) {
    return str.charAt(index).toLowerCase();
}
function getUpperCase(str, index) {
    return str.charAt(index).toUpperCase();
}
```

expected result of Json Values:

**List of Users:


123Admin

321user

!testAdmin

#adminData

jane doe

Jane Smith

john doe

John Doe**

Current results of Json Values:
**List of Users:


!testAdmin

#adminData

123Admin

321user

Jane Smith

jane doe

john doe**

It still follows the Ascii default order of sort.

Comment: @SalmanA I called the .sort() function in populating the tables for DataTable sir.

`
function populateTables() {
  getAll().then((data) => {
    data.sort(getSortOrder("username"));
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach suggested by Nina Scholz is more concise, but here is what was wrong with your original code:

Your `isLetter` function does not return the correct result. Using the `RegExp.test` method as below would fix that:

```
function isLetter(str, index) {
  return str.charAt(index).length === 1 && /^[a-z]/i.test(str);
}
```

Your `getSortOrder` function also does not handle sorting correctly when comparing characters that belong to different groups (special character / number / letter). To fix that, you could change that function to distinguish when the characters are in the same group versus when they are in different groups:

```
function getSortOrder(a, b) {
  if (isNumeric(a, 0) && isNumeric(b, 0)) return sortData(a, b);
  if (isSpecialChar(a, 0) && isSpecialChar(b, 0)) return sortData(a, b);
  if (isLetter(a, 0) && isLetter(b, 0)) return sortData(a, b);
  if (isNumeric(a, 0)) return -1;
  if (isLetter(a, 0)) return 1;
  if (isSpecialChar(a, 0)) {
    if (isNumeric(b, 0)) return 1;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Finally, the `sortData` function does not distinguish between lower and upper case. It would need to do something like this:

```
function sortData(a, b) {
    const aLower = a[0].toLowerCase();
    const bLower = b[0].toLowerCase();
    if (aLower === bLower) {
        if (a[0] === aLower && b[0] !== bLower) return -1;
        if (a[0] !== aLower && b[0] === bLower) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    if (aLower < bLower) return -1;
    if (aLower > bLower) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. code is working but there's a bit off where "TestData" comes first rather than "testData" is this bug sir?

Comment: Yes, your `sortData` function does not distinguish between lower and upper case. I've added this to the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a brute force approach with an string/object for the wanted order.

This appriach iterate each pair of strings and check any character by getting the order until finding different characters.

```js
const
   chars = ' 0123456789!@#$%^=+abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
   order = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(chars, ((c, i) => [c, i + 1]))),
   sort = (a, b) => {
       for (let i = 0, l = Math.min(a.length, b.length); i < l; i++) {
           const r = order[a[i].toLowerCase()] - order[b[i].toLowerCase()];
           if (r) return r;
       }
       return a.length - b.length;
   },
   sortBy = (fn, k) => (a, b) => fn(a[k], b[k]),
   data = [{ name: 'abcd' }, { name: 'abc' }, { name: 'John Doe' }, { name: '!testAdmin' }, { name: '#adminData' }, { name: '123Admin' }, { name: '321user' }, { name: 'Jane Smith' }, { name: 'jane doe' }, { name: 'john doe' }];

data.sort(sortBy(sort, 'name'));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can I ask if how can I put this inside the getSortOrder(prop) function with parameter prop = username so that it is specified to sort the username only? when I tried this the Date was only sorted and it ignores the username order.

Comment: @FatalError, please see edit.

Comment: if its okay may I ask if how can I make the small letter comes first from the Capital letter ones?

Comment: please add an example which shows the problem. actually you have a mixed result of lower and upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can be used in a sort.

It starts with finding the index of the first uncommon character between the lower case strings.

Then assigns the order (-1,0,+1) depending on a priority, and then the order of the lower case strings.

```js
 function newSort(a, b) {
   let lca = a.toLowerCase();
   let lcb = b.toLowerCase();
   let len = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
   let i = 0; 
   // find index of first uncommon character
   while(lca[i] === lcb[i] && i<len) i++;
   // what priority do the types of the uncommon character get
   let prioA = !lca[i] ? 0 : /^\d/.test(lca[i]) ? 1 : /^[a-z]/.test(lca[i]) ? 3 : 2;
   let prioB = !lcb[i] ? 0 : /^\d/.test(lcb[i]) ? 1 : /^[a-z]/.test(lcb[i]) ? 3 : 2;
   let order = prioA > prioB ? 1 : prioA < prioB ? -1
         : lca > lcb ? 1 : lca < lcb ? -1 : 0;
   return order
 } 

  const stringArray = [
  "1!a", "1a!", "!1a", "!a1", "a!1", "a1!" 
, "Jane Smith" , "jane doe" , "john doe"
, "abcX", "ABC", "DEFy", "defx"
];

 let sortedStringArray = stringArray.sort(newSort);
 console.log(sortedStringArray);
```

Comment: May I ask if how can I ignore if there's "0" in the first index of string and just start it with "1" ?

Comment: I guess you could remove the leading zero's from lca & lcb? `let lca = a.toLowerCase().replace(/^0+(?=\d)/, '');`